# How to fill HashMap object only once for program?

Tags: java, static, hashmap, instantiation

Given the following portion of my wider program:

```
public class AnimalNames {
  private static String[] animalNames = {dog, cat, horse, cow, donkey, elephant};
  private static String[] animalNameAbbreviations = {d, c, h, co, d, e};
  public static HashMap<String, String> getAnimalNameTranslations() {
    HashMap<String, String> animalNameTranslations = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < animalNames.length; i++) {
      animalNameTranslations.put(animalNameAbbreviations[i], animalNames[i])
    }
    return animalNameTranslations;
  }
}
```

I'm able to access the filled animalNameTranslations (using the static keyword) without instantiating the AnimalNames class, which is what I want. However, my program still has to fill animalNameTranslations every time I want to access it (using the for loop). Is there a way to fill the HashMap object only once for my program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the `getAnimalNameTranslations` method from your static initializer block, which would be executed once, when the class is initialized. You'll have to add a static member that holds the Map returned by the method.

For example :

```
private static HashMap<String, String> animalNameTranslations;
static {
    animalNameTranslations = getAnimalNameTranslations ();
}
```

Or just move the logic of that method directly to the static initializer block.

```
  private static HashMap<String, String> animalNameTranslations;
  static {
    animalNameTranslations = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < animalNames.length; i++) {
      animalNameTranslations.put(animalNameAbbreviations[i], animalNames[i])
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare your `animalNameTranslations` as a private static variable, and then update your `getAnimalNameTranslations()` method to initialize `animalNameTranslations` only if it hasn't been previously initialize like this:

```
public class AnimalNames {
  private static HashMap<String, String> animalNameTranslations;
  public static HashMap<String, String> getAnimalNameTranslations() {
    if(animalNameTranslations == null) {
      animalNameTranslations = new HashMap<String, String>();
      for (int i = 0; i < animalNames.length; i++)
        animalNameTranslations.put(animalNameAbbreviations[i], animalNames[i])
    }
    return animalNameTranslations;
  }
}
```

This will avoid coupling your callers to a data structure in your class, encapsulating your underlying implementation.

Now something to pay attention to is that previously, your data structure will be updated every time `getAnimalNameTranslations()` is called. With my suggested approach, if your `animalNames` and `animalNameAbbreviations` ever changed, you will need separate methods like, `addAnimalNameTranslations()`, `deleteAnimalNameTranslations()` etc. to update your underlying data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
public class AnimalNames {
      private static String[] animalNames = {dog, cat, horse, cow, donkey, elephant};
      private static String[] animalNameAbbreviations = {d, c, h, co, d, e};
      private static HashMap<String, String> animalNameTranslations = new HashMap<String, String>();
      static{
         for (int i = 0; i < animalNames.length; i++) {
          animalNameTranslations.put(animalNameAbbreviations[i], animalNames[i])
         }
      }
      public static HashMap<String, String> getAnimalNameTranslations() {
        return animalNameTranslations;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the static blocks to resolve your problem.
Also called Static initialization blocks .
This is a normal block of code enclosed in braces, { }, and preceded by the static keyword. 
like this :

```
static {
    // add the code for initialization 
}
```

A class can have any number of static initialization blocks, and they can appear anywhere in the class body.
The runtime system guarantees that static initialization blocks are called in the order that they appear in the source code.

you can write your code as

```
private static HashMap<String, String> animalNameTranslations;
  static {
    animalNameTranslations = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < animalNames.length; i++) {
      animalNameTranslations.put(animalNameAbbreviations[i], animalNames[i])
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hardcode the map. Sure it's brute force and it seems archaic, but it's fast and built for you at compile time, no waiting for any code to run ever. If everything's static anyway and the list won't be changing, it's a huge win.

If you still want to run some startup code, do it in a static initializer, once for the program.

Comment: Thanks, your answer sounds interesting. Could you please explain what you mean by 'hardcode the map'? A brief example would be helpful.

Comment: Oops, sorry. The hardcoded syntax is limited. A shame that there are data some data structures that you have to construct at runtime instead of just casting it. I know, this violates encapsulation to a certain extent, but it forces simple solutions to be raised to a higher level of sophisticated to work, which just ticks me off. A map is just a list of pairs; it should have a static form that just eats a static hardcoded list of pairs without needing any user runtime code at all. Grr.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define a private member and fill variable by it:

```
private static HashMap<String, String> _animalNameTranslations = new HashMap<String, String>();
public static HashMap<String, String> getAnimalNameTranslations() {
    var animalNameTranslations = _animalNameTranslations;
    for (int i = 0; i < animalNames.length; i++) {
      animalNameTranslations.put(animalNameAbbreviations[i], animalNames[i])
    }
    return animalNameTranslations;
  }
```

Comment: Aside from the problem that `var animalNameTranslations` is not legal Java code (you're a C# guy?), how does this avoid filling the hash map multiple times? It seems it's just the code from the question with a local variable moved outside, which doesn't change anything. Where you perhaps thinking of [isim's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30554310/1521179) but didn't quite think it through?